# How do I make a justify content between in the navbar of bootstrap separating the logo from the nav items

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

This is my html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" alt="">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is my css

```
/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 45px; */
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.logo {
  height: 30px;
}
```

I want the logo to be on the far left and the nav-items together on the far right , I was adding a justify content to the container but did not work , any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign class `justify-content-end` to the `#navbarNavDropdown` div.

I also added `px-lg-5` after `container-fluid` as to show all text in dropdown menu.

```css
/* Navbar */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 45px; */
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.logo {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid px-lg-5">
    <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" alt="">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown link
              </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

On the other hand, you are using Bootstrap-5 instead of Bootstrap-4.